# Can I calculate the limit of a multivariable function by firstly substituting one of the variable limit?

Tags: calculus

I am dealing with a calculus problem.

The Question is:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{\sin(xy^2)}{x\cos(xy)}$$

My answer is:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{\sin(xy^2)}{x\cos(xy)}= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x\cos x}= 1$$

The answer in the textbook is:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{\sin(xy^2)}{x\cos(xy)}= \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{xy^2}{x\cos(xy)} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{y^2}{\cos(xy)}= 1$$

**Although our results are the same, I am still wondering whether or not I can deal with this problem by substituting one of the variable's limit first.**

If I can continue addressing problems in my old way, can you explain to me why? If not, can you give me the reasons?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is not valid. You are only proving that the limit as $(x,y) \to (0,1)$ along the line $y=1$ is $1$. But there are other ways in which $(x,y)$ can approach $(0,1)$.

If you know before hand that the limit exists then you can find the value of the limit by putting $y=1$ first and then taking limit as $ x \to 0$.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: Oh, very sorry; I must have mistyped on my phone. If you edit, I can change it...

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understood why my answer is wrong. Thanks a lot!!!